# The constructor ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(Context, int, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) is undefined

Tags: android, arraylist, undefined, custom-adapter, horizontallist

I am totally new to Android.

This question might be a basic one.

But I'm struggling for four days with this. Please Help me.

I'm making horizontal listview for providing the contents of several categories from blog.

(similar interface with Pulse news app)

I got the open source of the horizontal listview and I'm modifying it.

This code is `CustomArrayAdapter.java`.

But when I try to write `super()`; inside the constructor, it makes an error like this :

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(Context, int, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) is undefined
```

And eclipse suggests like this :

```
Remove argument to match 'ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(Context, int)'
```

I don't know where this (Context, int) argument came from.

Please check what is wrong in `CustomArrayAdapter.java` below :

```
package com.xxxx.xxxxxxxxx;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/** An array adapter that knows how to render views when given CustomData classes */
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private int viewId;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super(c, textViewResourceId, d);

        this.context = c;
        this.viewId = textViewResourceId;
        this.data = d; 
    }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
         return data.size();
     }

    /*
     * We are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
     * list item will look.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        // Assign the view we are converting to a local variable
        View vi = convertView;
        Holder holder;      

        if (convertView == null) {

            // Inflate the view since it does not exist
            if (vi == null) {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_data_view, null);
            }

            /*
             * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this method.
             * The variable simply refers to the position of the current object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter
             * iterates through the list we sent it)
             * 
             * Therefore, i refers to the current Item object.
             */

            // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
            // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.

            // Create and save off the holder in the tag so we get quick access to inner fields
            // This must be done for performance reasons

            holder = new Holder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_view);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_view);

            vi.setTag(holder);                                  

        } else {
            holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
        }

        // check to see if each individual textview is null.
        // if not, assign some text!
        // Populate the text 

        HashMap<String, String> currentData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        currentData = data.get(position);

        if (currentData != null) {
            holder.textView.setText(currentData.get(MainActivity.KEY_TITLE));
            holder.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());    
            holder.imageLoader.DisplayImage(currentData.get(MainActivity.KEY_THUMBNAIL), holder.imageView);
        }       

        // Set the color
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        return vi;
    }

    /** View holder for the views we need access to */
    private static class Holder {
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. check the public constructors of arrayadapter. where do you invoke your custom adapter?

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for your comment. Actually I had already checked that page, but I couldn't find what is wrong at that time. Fortunately, the problem has solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me :) I modified the code as you guided and now it is working properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you to change this

```
super(c, textViewResourceId, d);
```

to

```
super(c, textViewResourceId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, surely I tried it. But calling _super(c, textViewResourceId);_ without argument d produced another problem - it made the item count of listview as zero. So I had to fight with IndexOutOfBoundsException in that case.