# How to check values in HashMap<String, String> and setBackgroundResource when record = value?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap, android-studio-2.1

I have just started coding an Android App using Android Studio 2.1 and my app was sort of an offline messaging - this is using SQLite Database (basically compose of two tables message and contact).

I am now in my last activity where I need to populate a list of message exchange from the contacts created. I was able to list them but without aesthetics. I would like to set different setBackgroundResource whenever the type is either a LEFT or RIGHT but was struggling to apply it.
Below is my code:

MessageRepo - the SQLite DBhelper:

```
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getMessageListById(int fromid, int toid) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String toquery = "SELECT " + MessageModel.messageId +
            ", " + MessageModel.fromId +
            ", " + MessageModel.toId +
            ", " + MessageModel.messageContent +
            ", 'RIGHT' AS type FROM " + MessageModel.tableMessage +
            " WHERE " + MessageModel.toId +
            " = ? AND " + MessageModel.fromId +
            " = ? ";
    String fromquery = "SELECT " + MessageModel.messageId +
            ", " + MessageModel.fromId +
            ", " + MessageModel.toId +
            ", " + MessageModel.messageContent +
            ", 'LEFT' AS type FROM " + MessageModel.tableMessage +
            " WHERE " + MessageModel.fromId +
            " = ? AND " + MessageModel.toId +
            " = ? ";
    String query = toquery +
            " UNION " + fromquery +
            " ORDER BY " + MessageModel.messageId;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messageList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(fromid), String.valueOf(toid), String.valueOf(fromid), String.valueOf(toid)});
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
            messages.put("messageId", cursor.getString(0));
            messages.put("messageFromId", cursor.getString(1));
            messages.put("messageToId", cursor.getString(2));
            messages.put("messageContent", cursor.getString(3));
            messages.put("type", cursor.getString(4));
            messageList.add(messages);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return messageList;
}
```

Message Activity - this will display in a ListView but not working as I was intending it to display:

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messageList = messagehandler.getMessageListById(_fromid, _toid);
    if (messageList.size() != 0) {
        ListView listView = getListView();
        if(messageList.contains("RIGHT")) {
            listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right);
        } else {
            listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.left);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MessageDetailActivity.this, messageList, R.layout.message, new String[]{"messageFromId", "messageToId", "messageContent"}, new int[]{R.id.FromId, R.id.ToId, R.id.message});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

I've checked a lot of posts and I can't seem to make it work for me:
[The constructor ArrayAdapter>>(Context, int, ArrayList>) is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775077/the-constructor-arrayadapterarraylisthashmapstring-stringcontext-int-a)
[Android Alternate row Colors in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109840/android-alternate-row-colors-in-listview)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit more. I finally found the answer by opting to use List and a setter/getter class:

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactsAndMessages> {

public MessagesAdapter(Context context, List<ContactsAndMessages> contacts) {
    super(context, 0, contacts);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ContactsAndMessages contact = getItem(position);

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica.ttf");

    if(convertView == null) {
        if (contact.type.equalsIgnoreCase("me")) {....
```